# Set-up a File Location that is not on a standard port

Tags: marketing-cloud, security, sftp

According to documentation Marketing Cloud will only allow connections on the stardard 21/22 ports. The client has a security policy that doesn't allow access to standard ports.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_file_locations.htm&type=5

Has anyone else run into this issue? If so, how have you resolved this.

Comment: I would raise a support case and ask whether you can use an alternative port for connection.

Comment: Yeah, I did. They just pointed me to the documentation again. I was hoping someone has figured out a work around for this...